# What does "in spades" mean?

Tags: phrases

What does "in spades" mean, for example in the following sentence:

> demand and love are both there in spades ...

I guess "in spades" means "on cards" or "on the table" or exist?

Comment: “In abundance; very much.”  See [wiktionary](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/in_spades), [thefreedictionary](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/in+spades), [phrases.org.uk](http://www.phrases.org.uk/meanings/in-spades.html), etc.

Comment: Looking up the meaning of a word or phrase is precisely what dictionaries are there for. Please use them. If you still have questions left after that, we welcome them, but this site is not meant as a dictionary lookup service. In fact looking up something in a dictionary of your choice is much, much faster than typing up an entire question here. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

In the card game of "Bridge" the suits of cards (hearts, diamonds, clubs and spades) have ranks, with spades being the highest rank.  Making the Ace of Spades the top card, as it were.

When you say you have something "in spades" you have a great abundance of it, or a high degree of quality of it.

See "[In Spades](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/in_spades)" in Wikionary.

Comment: "I not only have X, but I have it *in spades*" would then mean to have the best kind of X there is. I think the meaning of "quantity" came next, but it's definitely there now.

Comment: Yes, @AndrewS, I believe you're right!

Answer (score 1):

According to NOAD, *in spades* is a set expression that means:

> *informal* to a very high degree: *he got his revenge now in spades.*